# Distance to "boundary" of a polyhedral complex

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra, convex-geometry

Suppose I have a [polyhedral complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_complex) $\{P_1, \ldots, P_k\}$ and let

$$S := \bigcup_{i = 1}^k P_i$$

I am interested in a function that measures the distance from a point $x \in S$ to the "boundary" of my polyhedral complex. In other words, the lower dimensional faces. More precisely, if $x \in \text{int}(P_i)$ for some $i$, then my function should return the distance from $x$ to the boundary of $P_i$. Otherwise, $x$ lies on a lower dimensional face and the function should return $0$.

Is there a name for this function? Has it appeared in the literature and been studied before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://hohmann.mit.edu/milp/MILP_for_Control.pdf).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you! Could you let me know which slide number(s) you are referring to?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sorry I missed that! Yes, $S$ is the union of convex polyhedra. But importantly these aren't just any convex polyhedra. They form a [polyhedral complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_complex).

Comment: How are those convex polyhedra defined? By a set of vertices or by the intersection of half-spaces?

Comment: Right now, I am just interested in theoretical properties of this distance function. So one could define them either way. Computation is obviously important though, so if there are any results on computing this distance function in either of those two cases then I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: One could always find the distance from a given point to each polyhedra by solving a collection of quadratic programs.There is no guarantee that one will find the desired point, but it is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! I'm not sure if there is a definition of this specifically for polyhedra, but here is what I know from a convex analysis perspetive:

The "distance function to the set $C$" is denoted $d_C(x)=\inf_{c\in C}\|x-c\|$. There are some really neat results for when $C$ is nonempty, closed and convex. However, as soon as we restrict to considering the case when $C$ is the boundary of some other set, then $C$ is frequently nonconvex. e.g. the closed $\ell_1$ ball is is a convex polyhedron, but its boundary is nonconvex.